# send2trash sends permission denied exception

Tags: python

When I run the python package send2trash that can be found [here](https://pypi.org/project/Send2Trash/),

```
send2trash("my_path")
```

where "my_path" is the path to the file I want to delete, I get:

```
raise OSError("Permission denied: %s" % path)
OSError: Permission denied: my_path.
```

The file has the right permission. How can I fix this problem?

Comment: What is the value of `my_path`? Is it literally `"my_path"`, as the error message suggests?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This usually happens when you try removing something that's above your current working directory. Try setting the working directory to a folder above the file you're trying to trash:

```
import os
os.chdir(my_path)
```

You can trash the current working directory but beware that doing that changes the current working directory automatically.

Comment: thanks ! how do I get the current working directory to change it back to the original value when I'm done?

Comment: Glad I could help! That'd be os.getcwd()

Comment: Maybe try running your program as administrator?

Answer (score 0):

My problem was solved by the answer above. However this is a good work around permissions programatically in python. I think other people might find it useful too.

```
subprocess.call(['chmod', '-R', '+w', "my_path"])
send2trash("my_path")
```